# Laravel Blade - Displaying array content

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I make calls to some APIs to fill up an array.  The end output is something like the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [leadData] => Array
        (
            [LeadID] => 1232806
            [DateIdentified] => 21/04/2016
            [Client] => Prospect 1
            [LeadName] => Test
            [Owner] => Some Owner
            [Value] => 2160.00
            [Status] => 70%
        )
        [clientData] => Array
        (
            [BusinessStructure] => 
            [IsProspect] => No
        )
        [quoteData] => Array
        (
            [QuoteID] => Q0020
            [ProjectName] => Test
            [Amount] => 1800.00
            [AmountTax] => 360.00
            [AmountIncludingTax] => 2160.00
            [EstimatedCost] => 450.00
            [EstimatedCostTax] => 90.00
            [EstimatedCostIncludingTax] => 540.00
        )
        [customData] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [Lead Type] => New 
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [Month] => June
            )
        )
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [leadData] => Array
        (
            [LeadID] => 1230279
            [DateIdentified] => 19/04/2016
            [Client] => Bank1
            [LeadName] => test 3
            [Owner] => Some Owner
            [Value] => 36000.00
            [Status] => 50%
        )
        [clientData] => Array
        (
            [BusinessStructure] => 
            [IsProspect] => No
        )
        [quoteData] => Array
        (
            [QuoteID] => Q0016
            [ProjectName] => test 3
            [Amount] => 30000.00
            [AmountTax] => 6000.00
            [AmountIncludingTax] => 36000.00
            [EstimatedCost] => 0.00
            [EstimatedCostTax] => 0.00
            [EstimatedCostIncludingTax] => 0.00
        )
    )
)
```

One thing to note is that sometimes not all of the information is there, simply because it is not available.  So you can see that Array 0 has some customData whereas Array 1 does not.  Other elements may not even have a quoteData section etc.

So my blade template now has this information.  I basically want to show all the data, but if it is not available, to just show an empty cell.  So I have the following headers

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover additionalMargin alignment">
    <tr class="col-md-12 noPadding">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Lead ID</th>
            <th>Client Name</th>
            <th>Is Prospect</th>
            <th>Business Structure</th>
            <th>Quote ID</th>
            <th>Project Name</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Amount Tax</th>
            <th>Amount inc Tax</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th>Cost Tax</th>
            <th>Cost inc Tax</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Month</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </tr>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, within the tbody, what I am doing seems very messy, the only way I can seem to get data in the correct place is if I check everything e.g.

```
@if(is_array($leadArray))
        @foreach($leadArray as $array)
            <tr>
                 <td>
                     @if(!empty($array['leadData']))
                        {{ $array['leadData']['LeadID'] }}
                     @endif
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     @if(!empty($array['leadData']))
                        {{ $array['leadData']['Client'] }}
                     @endif
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     @if(!empty($array['clientData']))
                        {{ $array['clientData']['IsProspect'] }}
                     @endif
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     @if(!empty($array['clientData']))
                        {{ $array['clientData']['BusinessStructure'] }}
                     @endif
                 </td>
                <td>
                    @if(!empty($array['quoteData']))
                        {{ $array['quoteData']['QuoteID'] }}
                    @endif
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if(!empty($array['quoteData']))
                        {{ $array['quoteData']['ProjectName'] }}
                    @endif
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if(!empty($array['quoteData']))
                        {{ $array['quoteData']['Amount'] }}
                    @endif
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     @if(!empty($array['quoteData']))
                        {{ $array['quoteData']['AmountTax'] }}
                     @endif
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     @if(!empty($array['quoteData']))
                         {{ $array['quoteData']['AmountIncludingTax'] }}
                     @endif
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     @if(!empty($array['quoteData']))
                        {{ $array['quoteData']['EstimatedCost'] }}
                     @endif
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     @if(!empty($array['quoteData']))
                        {{ $array['quoteData']['EstimatedCostTax'] }}
                     @endif
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     @if(!empty($array['quoteData']))
                         {{ $array['quoteData']['EstimatedCostIncludingTax'] }}
                     @endif
                 </td>
                @if(!empty($array['customData']))
                    @foreach($array['customData'] as $data)
                            <td>
                                @if(!empty($data['Lead Type']))
                                    {{ $data['Lead Type'] }}
                                @endif
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if(!empty($data['Month']))
                                    {{ $data['Month'] }}
                                @endif
                            </td>
                    @endforeach
                    @else
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                @endif
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

Is there a neater way to do this?  Or is this my only option?

Thanks

Comment: You could do `{{ @$array['leadData']['Client'] }}` to suppress errors when the data's missing. Or pre-process the array in a way that fills any missing data with `null`s.

Comment: @ceejayoz, interesting. Is it documented anywhere? If not, how exactly does it work?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin `@` is PHP's error suppression operator. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php for details. It should be used rarely, but yours looks like a potentially appropriate use case.

Comment: @ceejayoz, thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin See @JoelHinz's answer for a better option. I forgot about Laravel's `or`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blade has a feature where you can use `or` to mean "echo this if it exists, or this if it doesn't". So you can do

```
<td>{{ $array['leadData']['LeadID'] or '' }}</td>
```

And that basically results in what you want. Much cleaner, no? :)

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data - a few paragraphs down.

Comment: I'd forgotten about this one. Nice.

Comment: Thats actually very interesting - it seems to also check if its empty which means I do not need to do this

Comment: @Joel Hinz, it's interesting too, definitely upvote. In documentation they say it's checking for `isset()`. But does it check for `is_null()` and `empty`?

Comment: I'll answer myself. Looked under the hood, it does only `isset()` check.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Nope. But `isset()` returns false for null values. Empty arrays I believe would be printed as 1, since the isset evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

You also could do this more elegantly and shorter by iterating array with column names (used `or ''` as Joel advised):

```
{{ $dataColumns['leadData'] = ['LeadID', 'Client'] }}
{{ $dataColumns['clientData'] = ['IsProspect', 'BusinessStructure'] }}
{{ #dataColumns['quoteData'] = ['QuoteID', 'ProjectName', 'Amount', 'AmountTax', 'AmountIncludingTax', 'EstimatedCost', 'EstimatedCostTax', 'EstimatedCostIncludingTax'] }}

@if(is_array($leadArray))
    @foreach($leadArray as $array)
        <tr>
            @foreach($dataColumns as $dataColumn)
                @foreach($dataColumn as $column)
                    <td>{{ $array[$dataColumn][$column] or '' }}</td>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
            @if(!empty($array['customData']))
                @foreach($array['customData'] as $data)
                    <td>{{ $data['Lead Type'] or ''}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data['Month'] or '' }}</td>
                @endforeach
            @else
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
            @endif
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave this a try and it said that html eminities expects parameter 1 to be a string, array given

Comment: And in what line? Also, try to use `{!!   !!}` instead of `{{   }}`

Comment: It is difficult to say because it says ErrorException in helpers.php line 469:

Comment: Ok, then just change `{{` to `{!!` and it will not call `htmlentities()`

Comment: I think it was the column line it was complaining about.  If I use {{ it complains about expecting parameter 1 to be a string.  If I change it to {!! it gives me the error Array to string conversion

Comment: @kate_hudson, I rewrote the code. Problem was with data structure.